# Highlight custom widgets in the admin area?

Tags: wp-admin, widgets, sidebar, customization

I have created some custom widgets for my client to use, but I want to make them stand out amidst the fifteen or so standard widgets in the admin area. How can I do this?

*I have solved this problem myself and will place the solution here, but please feel free it add a better solution if you have one.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All widgets in the admin area get an `id` in the style `widget-[global_counter]_[widget_key]-[widget_id]`, like `widget-59_monkeyman_widget_shortcut-5` (installed widget) or `widget-11_monkeyman_widget_shortcut-__i__` (an uninstalled widget in the list).

If your widget key contains something unique for all your widgets (like your company name), you can use this and add a [substring attribute CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) (which [works in most browsers](http://www.css3.info/modules/selector-compat/)). In my case `div.widget[id*=_monkeyman_]` does the trick, so I add a little CSS snippet in the `widgets.php` admin page header:

```
add_action('admin_print_styles-widgets.php', 'monkeyman_widgets_style');
function monkeyman_widgets_style()
{
    echo <<<EOF
<style type="text/css">
div.widget[id*=_monkeyman_] .widget-title {
    color: #2191bf;
}
</style>
EOF;
}
```

This gives me the following result:
[image: Highlighted widgets amongst regular widgets]

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Nice! I wasn't familiar with this. Do you know the browsers it *does not* work with?

Comment: @Mike: [It appears only IE6 doesn't recognize it](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/). Maybe some Javascript can fill that gap, by adding an extra class?

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Bah! For admin side, IE6 users can just upgrade. :-)

Comment: @Jan: Keep in mind to not destroy the UI a user expects. Those changes are cool but can have a downside. Only that I have said it :)

Comment: @hakre: I would only do this on sites I created for clients, not in a plugin that others might use. So then the users are already used to whatever weird things I teach them!

Comment: cant really seem to get it to work .. you past the markup in the widgets.php you say? .. any specific place in the widgets.php?

Comment: @cap2core: You should not paste this in [the `wp-admin/widgets.php` file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/widgets.php), but in your own theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin you created. It then inserts the code every time someone loads the widgets admin page.