# Removing widget without using unregister_widget

Tags: widgets

I want to remove some plugin widget showing from wp-admin/widgets.php but i dont want to use unregister_widget because i am using this widget automatically from php files..

Basically i dont want clients see this widget as option in wp-admin/widgets.php but i want to use this widget from php files. I thought css display:none as solution but  widget div IDs are not static seems

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to call the code as a widget if you're not using the widget functionality? Why can't you just call the code without extending the widget class? Please update your question.

Comment: uhm.. probably i dont know the way to do that.. basically widget is from this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/
can you check it if its possible to use it from function properly?

Comment: That's a little bit too much code for a quick look. :) What do you want to achieve? If you need just one special output there is probably a simpler way.

Comment: this plugin creates widgets which i need but i am using those in functions.php without using widget panel. And i dont want my clients see this widget in their widget panel but if i disable it with unregister_widget, then widgets not working even from functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following answer, adapt the code and it will do what you want.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3005/12615

Use Firebug for Firefox, or Chrome/Safari inspector to discover the widget ID.

Note the use of CSS3 [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors), that allows targeting an element using a partial ID or Class.
For example, this will hide the Calendar widget:
`div.widget[id*=_calendar-] { display:none; }`