# Get the sidebar ID in which the current widget was dropped

Tags: customization, widgets, php, sidebar

How can I find out in which sidebar was a widget dropped? From inside that widget. More precisely from the `form()` function.

Can I automatically remove the widget if it's not added in the appropriate sidebar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread:

[Limit widget to certain sidebar?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/limit-widget-to-certain-sidebar)